# In SwiftUI how can I have a View exceed its parents frame/boundary in a List?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Consider the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  private var listContent: [String] = ["This", "is", "a", "placeholder", "list"]
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(listContent, id: \.self) { entry in
        listElement(text: entry)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct listElement: View {
  @State var text: String
  
  var body: some View {
    Section() {
      HStack {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(.green)
          .frame(width: 30, height: nil)
        Text(text)
      }
      .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    }
  }
}
```

which generates this

[image: code]

I would like to add additional markers to the left of each List element and/or section, like this (mockup):

[image: mockup]

I have the data that describes the width of the green bars leading into the list elements on the child and parent element. Coming from web development I expect to do something like a child element having negative margin and is thus exceeding its parents container. However I could not get it to work with SwiftUI's padding. Is there a way to do this?

---

For example I have tried the following modification to the previously mentioned listElement:

```
  var body: some View {
    Section() {
      HStack {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(.red)
          .frame(width: 30, height: 10)
          .padding(.leading, -20)
          .zIndex(9999)
        Rectangle()
          .fill(.green)
          .frame(width: 30, height: nil)
        Text(text)
      }
      .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    }
  }
```

which results in:

[image]

The red rectangle overflow is hidden. I've tried pushing it to the top with the dreaded `zIndex` hack but it doesn't work. Even setting the Lists `.scrollContentBackground` to `.hidden` and the `.background` to `.clear` doesn't show the red Rectangle. I need the overflow to be visible.

Comment: Can you please experiment with padding whose values are negative, and present your code and the result?

Comment: change style to plain and decorate your cells by yourself: `.listStyle(.plain)`. The default style is `insetGrouped`, which is hard to customize.

Comment: While that would work it'd also change the way `.swipeActions` look. I initially went for the `insetGrouped` look to also have the swipe actions inset. Unless there is a way to customize that?